# Constraint of a single True value in many-to-many through table BooleanField

Tags: python, django

I want to achieve the following:

1. *Listings* can be tagged under multiple *categories*
2. A *listing* can have at most one *main* category. This is the *category* that best describes it, of all the *categories* it is tagged with.
3. Admins should not be able to mark multiple *main categories* for a single *listing*.

In my `models.py` I have:

```python
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint, CheckConstraint

class Listing(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50),
  content = models.TextField(),
  categories = models.ManyToManyField(
    'Category',
    through='CategoryMembership',
    related_name='listings'
  )

class Category(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50),
                                      
class CategoryMembership(models.Model):
  listing = models.ForeignKey(
    Listing,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
  )
  category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
  )
  main_category = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  
  class Meta:
    constraints = [
      UniqueConstraint(
        name='unique_listing_category_membership',
        fields=['listing', 'category']
      )]
```

To achieve 2 and 3 I thought I could add another constraint to `CategoryMembership`'s `Meta` class. But I am not sure how to proceed as I do not want to prevent listings having multiple categories where `main_category == False` in the through table.

Is such a constraint possible? Or is there a smarter way to structure the models to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#condition

I would try:

```
UniqueConstraing(
    name='name', 
    fields=['listing'], 
    condition=Q(main_category=True),
)
```